# How to find elements in QMap spring-data-mongoDB queryDSL

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

we are using spring-boot 2.2.1 and query-dsl-mongoDB 4.2.1.

we are using spring-data.mongodb findAll method tp find books from book collection using
various predicates like bookUid, authorId, customerId, status, isbn and provisioningId.
I can able to construct for all the attributes except `bookInfo`.

Please find the sample collection for reference.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6036323daa819c04005cff68"),
    "bookUid" : "spring_boot",
    "authorId" : "602bc44827e37ca2ba281f54",
    "customerId" : "75e1c48e",
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "name" : "Spring boot",
    "statusTimestamp" : ISODate("2021-02-24T11:07:28.000Z"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "bookInfo" : {
        "isbn" : "240220211202",
        "provisioningId" : "240220211202"
    },
    "customInfo" : {},
    "version" : 1,
    "countryCode" : "CZ",
    "_class" : "book-collection"
}
```

And this is the Java class,

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    @WhiteSpaceTrim
    private String bookUid;

    private String authorId;
    private String customerId;
    private String status;
    private String name;
    private Date statusTimestamp;
    private boolean deleted;
    @WhiteSpaceTrim
    private Map<String, String> provisionInfo;
    private SmartObject customInfo;
    private int version;
    private String countryCode;
}
```

While looking into query DSL autogenerated class I see the types for BookInfo is `QMap`

> public final ext.java.util.QMap provisionInfo = new
> ext.java.util.QMap(forProperty("bookInfo"));

I tried to construct below predicate whether bookInfo matches the bey key and value

> Map<String, String> expre = new HashMap<>();
> expre.put(key, value);
> predicates.add(QBook.book.provisionInfo.in(expre).isTrue());

But no luck it was not working and thrown exception, Then tried following expression

> PathBuilder entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(Book.class,
> "bookInfo");
> predicates.add(entityPath.getMap("map", String.class, String.class).get(key).eq(value));

But it returns an empty collection always even though we have matching `isbn` or `provisioningId`.

I was looking into the documentation but I couldn't find any help either.

Any help would be really appreciable.

Comment: try ```QBook.book.provisionInfo.get(key).eq(value)```

Comment: @Harshit Thank you for your reply. That is possible if the type of the BookInfo is `    public final MapPath<String, String, StringPath> bookInfo = this.<String, String, StringPath>createMap("bookInfo", String.class, String.class, StringPath.class);` but here the type is QMap.  QMap doesn't offer any get method

Comment: Could you test the code against the new QueryDSL 4.4.0?

Comment: Yes already did that but it’s the same .....problem is one of the class extends map so query dsl uses QMap for all the map attributes